# GREP function in KSH which ignores LINE Breaks

Tags: grep, line-breaks

I am using a grep command with two patterns in my KSH script.
File has line breaks in it and both the patterns are in different lines.
Here is the command -

```
grep -l 'RITE AID.*ST.820' natriter820u.20140914
Pattern1 - RITE AID
Pattern2 - ST*820
```

I am not getting any results from this, whereas if I replace this file with a different file having no line breaks then it works.
Is there any work around to deal with line breaks here.

Here is the sample data:-

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*NATIONSBANK    *14*0030020520500  *140918*1200*U*00401*000006436*0*P*^
GS*RA*014578892*IGIHCJEEJ*20140918*1200*6442*X*004010
ST*820*000006482
N1*PR*RITE AID HDQTRS. CORP.*1*014578892
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. `grep` is line oriented.

You can't get it to match like that.

You can get it to match lines with *either* pattern though by using alternation.

```
grep -l 'RITE AID\|ST.820' natriter820u.20140914
```

To find a file that has both matches you need to chain your calls to `grep` or use some other tool (like `awk`).

```
grep 'RITE AID' natriter820u.20140914 | grep -q 'ST.820' && echo natriter820u.20140914
```

To operate on single files with awk:

```
awk '/RITE AID/{pat1++} /ST.820/{pat2++} pat1&&pat2{print FILENAME; exit}' natriter820u.20140914
```

To operate on multiple files (like grep):

```
gawk '/A/{p1++} /d/{p2++} p1&&p2{print FILENAME; p1=0; p2=0; nextfile}' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Comment: Thanks Etan, but this will give all the files which will have any one of these patterns which is not the requirement. Is there any other way to have the desired results?